# What is another way to bind properties of a selected item other than using BindingContext?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

What is another way to bind properties of a selected item other than using `BindingContext`?

ListView: The following is my method for selecting an item of a list:

```
async void OnListItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ((App)App.Current).ResumeAtDatabaseId = (e.SelectedItem as DatabaseItem).ID;
            Debug.WriteLine("setting ResumeAtDatabaseId = " + (e.SelectedItem as DatabaseItem).ID);

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new DatabaseItemView
            {
                BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as DatabaseItem
            });
        }
```

ItemView: this is showing that right now `SetBinding` is being used to bind data between the two views.

```
public DatabaseItemView ()
        {
            //InitializeComponent ();

            //Name
            Name = new Entry
            {
                Placeholder = "Name"
            };
            Name.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "Name");            

            //Date
            Date = new DatePicker
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.Date
            };
            Date.SetBinding(DatePicker.DateProperty, "Date");
...
```

This is currently working. I would like more control over this binding and data value setting though.

Comment: What do you mean by "more control"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Slepz the way it works now, if I were to change the `"Name"` of `Name.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "Name");` it will no longer work. I'm looking for an alternative that doesn't utilize `BindingContext` and rely on exact spelling of a `string`.

Comment: Binding doesn't work without a BindingContext.  There really isn't an alternative other than explicitly assigning values;

Comment: @Jason explicitly assigning values would be the way to go if data needed to be handled, correct? I'm not aware of a way to use `BindingContext` and also transform that data.

Comment: I had the same problem, but now I use nameof() to avoid accidental refactor breaking. It's available in C# 6 and up. All my bindings look like this now and it works well for me: turnToBacksightButton.SetBinding(IsVisibleProperty, new Binding(path: nameof(_vm.CanAimAtBacksight), source: _vm));

Comment: it would help a lot if you provided a concrete example of something you want to do that cannot be handled due to binding.